# How to list all files in a directory Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, sqlite, directory

I need some quick code just to see what files are listed when I run the code for the current directory.

I have an SQLite database file which I would like my Silverlight Application to use but I don't know where to put it as I can't find what directory the application is working from.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you cannot access the local filesystem in Silverlight - it runs in it's own sandbox.  You should be able to deploy your SQLite db as part of your solution, so it's available from the sandbox.  Or you can expose your db via a webservice, and then your Silverlight app can use service calls to talk to the db.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a basic way to use a web service to gain access to the file on the server? thanks.

Comment: Here's a project (looks like Python) that exposes a SQLite db as a webservice.  http://code.google.com/p/restful-sqlite.  If your data is going to be read-only, then you might try using oData.  Here's a article on creating a C# oData service - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx